# Dlink Dir-300 err: New router not detected

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I bought new dlink router today but i am getting this error, new router not detected and the url: 192.168.0.1 is also not opening, however though setup is not complete the router is visible on mobile (but i cant use the net).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you physically connecting to the router?  The wireless is usually off by default on routers.  If you are connecting to the LAN port, try making sure you have a connection.  Open a command prompt (click start then Run on WindowsXP) and run `ipconfig`.  Make sure you have an IP address and a default gateway.  If you do have both of those make sure the default gateway is 192.168.0.1.  If it's not, try typing the address of your default gateway into a web browser and see if that brings up your routers config page.

Hope that helps!